# QGIS WFS doesn't load geometry

Tags: qgis, wfs

For some time I have had problems loading WFS Layers into my QGIS regardless of the QGIS version.
Everytime I add a Layer the metadata is still included in the attribute table but neither the Layer overview nor in the map geometry is displayed. I've added a screenshot for insight. (WFS is Baumbestand Berlin - Straßenbäume)

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it open data ? Could you share the url ?

Comment: Yes it's open data! The URL is https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/berlin/service_intern.jsp?id=s_wfs_baumbestand@senstadt&type=WFS 
The WFS-Adress is  https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_baumbestand

Comment: The URL you provided works for me!

Comment: in the question you say WFS, but the image has the layer listed as WMS, is that just an odd group name, or are you trying to load it as a WMS?

Comment: WFS works for me in QGIS.  QGIS sends requests like: `https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_baumbestand?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=fis:s_wfs_baumbestand&STARTINDEX=3000&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! 
The Layer I loadad is a WFS Layer. It just sliped in the WFS group due to poor layer hygiene...
If I use this Link ( https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_baumbestand?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=fis:s_wfs_baumbestand&STARTINDEX=3000&COUNT=1000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833 ) the WFS Layer loads as normal. I don't know why that is... 
I still have the same problem with other WFS layers...